# .htaccess trailing null

Tags: .htaccess

For some reason we seem to be seeing lots of 404 errors with all requested URLs going to a valid link but with a trailing /null. I don't know where this is coming from as it's not in the front end code.

For example: http://domain.com/valid/valid/null

Since I can't find the source of these trailing nulls I'd like to remove them with htaccess but I'm not having much luck:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/null]*)/null$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [NC,R=301]
```

My .htaccess knowledge is a little rusty. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Much better to fix the problem. If you provide more details about it, perhaps we can help you with that.

Comment: `[]` signifies a character group. `[^/null]` means any character that is not `/`, `n`, `u`, or `l`, and not any string that is not `/null` as you seem to expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is best to discover the source of the error as mentioned above.

If you need a respite while looking for it, the rules below, placed in .htaccess file in the root directory of your site, should strip out a trailing `/null`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#remove trailing null
RewriteRule ^(.+)/null$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [NC,L,R=301]
```

Comment: Hello Ulrich,

This did the trick.  I completely agree we need to find the source.  The website itself is very complex and I'm struggling to track down the source of the null links.  Have you (or any of the other responders) any tips on how to trace the problem links?  Many thanks!

Comment: @Studio4 I would start by grepping apache logs for cases of this URL and look at the referer to determine page where these links originated. If its on your site and still reproducible, it should be relatively easy to track by looking at code that generated these links.